# Install pthreads for PHP on CentOS

Tags: php, pthreads, centos

I tried 1 month to install pthreads on my CentOS x64 6.x. My server is running apache2 and php 5.3.3 with Zend Engine 2.3.0. My problem is same with many others people, when I try installing 'pecl install pthreads' it said:

> configure: error: in .....-0.0.45(pthread version)
>
> Configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

I try to google but not luck. Hope someone can advance it to me. Thanks a lot
Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 4):

You need to install a compiler and build tools, something like

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
```

Should get you a working build environment.